# What's the difference between using method's return values and leaving them?

Tags: java, memory, return-value

Below, you see two really simple Java programs. In the *first* program I didn't use the return value of the `returnTrue()` method and in the *second* program I assign it to a static field.

First program:

```
package test;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        returnTrue();
        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }

    public static boolean returnTrue() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Second program:

```
package test;
public class Test {
    public static boolean Result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result = returnTrue();
        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }

    public static boolean returnTrue() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Both worked fine and `"Finished!"` printed in the output.

Now, I want to know what happens in memory if I put the line with `returnTrue()` in an infinite loop? As far as I know, in the *second* program it assigns `true` to a specific address (i.e. the address of `Result`) in memory infinitely. (Right?)

But I don't have any idea about the *first* program. What happens in that situation? Does the JRE select a random address and assign all the return values to the same address? Or it assigns each return value to a specific address? Or even it leaves it and doesn't assign it to any address?

Comment: Can you show us final code of programs which behaviour you want to explore?

Comment: No. You have no control over the memory addresses - the new object, the `return` value - will always be allocated in memory. A _reference_ to that address will then be created. That _reference_ is **passed by value**. Whether you assign it to a variable or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Sounds like you're wondering what happens when a function returns a value but you don't assign the value to any variable. Nothing happens -- the value doesn't get stored anywhere; the JVM just drops it on the floor.

Comment: You might enjoy reading about how call stacks work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: Exceptions are caught: return values are stored. Please don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: @EJP Which kind of exception?

Comment: Seems like you need to start with [the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) before asking about the function of the internals of the JVM.

Comment: @Andremoniy It seems that our friends here don't need to the final code. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a method returns, the return value is typically left on the thread's stack in memory, wherever the calling code left off. A [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) is an important data structure commonly used for this purpose.

Suppose we had some code like the following:

```
void m1() {
    int i;
    int j;
    boolean b = m2();
}

boolean m2() {
    float f;
    float g;
    return true;
}
```

When `m1` begins executing, the stack begins extending to reserve space for the local variables:

```
int
int
boolean
```

`m2` is called and the stack extends again:

```
int
int
boolean
    float
    float
```

`m2` returns, and the stack unwinds in reverse order:

```
int
int
boolean
```

Notice that the last space on the stack is conveniently our local variable for the return value of `m2`, where `true` gets stored.

When you assign the return value to something, the primitive value or object reference gets copied from the stack to the location you assign it to (in this case the static field).

If you don't assign it to anything, the return value is simply ignored.

> […] what happens in memory if I put the line with `returnTrue()` in an infinite loop?

It performs the steps above repeatedly.

> Does the JRE select a random address and assign all the return values to the same address? Or it assigns each return value to a specific address?

See above, it gets put on the stack.

Comment: _When you assign the return value to something, the value gets copied from the stack to the location you assign it to_. This is not strictly speaking true, Java passes _references_ by value; except in the case of primitives.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In which case the value of the reference is copied.

Comment: When I assign it to the static field that stack address that it occupied before freed and reused for next call, right? In contrast when I don't assign it, the next call use another stack address, right? Doesn't it make stack over flow error?

Comment: My point exactly; you make it sound as though the entire memory location of the object is copied.

Comment: @Abraham *"Doesn't it make stack over flow error?"* A stack extends and unwinds periodically. You should read the call stack link posted in the comments under the main question.

Comment: @Abraham no. The memory location used by the reference is _reused_, but the memory allocated to the object itself becomes eligible for GC once there are no references to it. At some future point, that memory would become GC'd.